# Org mode - do statistic with remote table

Tags: org-mode

Can we do statistic with remote table?

Say TBL2 row1 is min of TBL1 columns,TBL2 row2 is max of TBL1 columns.
I write formula as below but it doesn't work!

```
#+NAME: TBL1
|  2 |  3 |
|  4 |  5 |
|  7 | 10 |
| 12 | 1  | 

#+NAME: TBL2
| #ERROR | #ERROR |
| #ERROR | #ERROR |
#+TBLFM: @1$1='(seq-min remote(TBL1,$1))::@1$2='(seq-min remote(TBL1,$2))::@2$1='(seq-max remote(TBL1,$1))::@2$2='(seq-max remote(TBL1,$2))
```

expected output is:

```
#+NAME: TBL2
|  2 |  1 |
| 12 | 10 |
```

Comment: Part of the problem is that the remote call returns the required bits and pieces of the remote table as strings. Enabling formula debugging might provide more information and allow you to convert what `remote` returns to the form that `seq-min` expects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Should not use '$1' to access column1 values, but use '@1$1..@1$>'.
2. Should use calcFunc vector functions 'calcFunc-v**', vmin/vmax for this case.

```

```
#+NAME: TBL1
|  2 |  3 |
|  4 |  5 |
|  7 | 10 |
| 12 | 1  | 

#+NAME: TBL2
|  2 |  1 |
| 12 | 10 |
#+TBLFM: @1$1=vmin(remote(TBL1,@1$1..@>$1))::@1$2=vmin(remote(TBL1,@1$2..@>$2))::@2$1=vmax(remote(TBL1,@1$1..@>$1))::@2$2=vmax(remote(TBL1,@1$2..@>$2))
```

```

Comment: In 1. the range should be @1$1..@>$1 i.e. first row to last row in column 1.

Comment: In 2. the formula could be done in elisp: `#+TBLFM: @1$1 = '(seq-min (mapcar #'string-to-number (list remote(TBL1, @1$1..@>$1))))` but the calc solution in the answer is certainly preferable.

Answer (score 0):

In `TBLFM` row, you must use [Emacs `calc` syntax](http://orgmode.org/manual/Formula-syntax-for-Calc.html) to do calculations, not emacs lisp syntax.  So the `seq-min` in your `TBLFM` will not work.

Comment: That's not true: you can use lisp syntax as shown in the OP's table. See [Formula syntax in lisp](http://orgmode.org/manual/Formula-syntax-for-Lisp.html#Formula-syntax-for-Lisp).

Comment: Oh, sorry for my wrong answer.